# PyQt5 QListView drag and drop creates new hidden items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 QListview with a list of items which can be rearranged by dragging and dropping and a checkbox selected. The problem is when I rearrange the items in the list the items rearrange correctly in the GUI but when I attempt to save the output there is a copy of the moved item in both its original and new position.

Function for creating the list

```
def create_methods_list(self):
    self.methods_list = QListView()
    self.methods_list.setDragDropMode(QListView.InternalMove)
    self.methods_list.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
    self.methods_list.setDragDropMode(False)
    self.methods_list.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.methods_list.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
    self.methods_list.setDragEnabled(True)
    self.methods_list.setWindowTitle('Method Order')

    self.methods_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.methods_list)

    # self.methods is a list of strings
    for method in self.methods:
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(method)
        item.setData(method)
        item.setCheckable(True)
        item.setDragEnabled(True)
        item.setDropEnabled(False)
        item.setCheckState(True)

        self.methods_model.appendRow(item)

    self.methods_model.itemChanged.connect(self.method_item_changed)
    self.methods_list.setModel(self.methods_model)
```

The function called when the list is rearranged:

```
def method_item_changed(self):
    print(self.methods_model.rowCount())
    i = 0
    new_methods = []
    while self.methods_model.item(i):
        if self.methods_model.item(i).checkState():
            new_methods.append(self.methods_model.item(i).data())
        i += 1
    print(new_methods)
    self.methods = new_methods
```

The first print statement returns one higher than the number of items in the original list. The second print statement returns the items in a list but the moved item is both in its original and new position.

I've tried a solution which included adding a QTimer with a short interval but that did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full working version:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
QAction, QWidget, QLabel, QDesktopWidget,
QApplication, QComboBox, QPushButton, QGridLayout,
QMainWindow, qApp, QVBoxLayout, QSlider,
QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QListView, QAbstractItemView
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.methods = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.layout.addStretch()
        self.create_methods_list()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.methods_list)
        self.layout.addStretch()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.show()

    def create_methods_list(self):
        self.methods_list = QListView()
        self.methods_list.setDragDropMode(QListView.InternalMove)
        self.methods_list.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.methods_list.setDragDropMode(False)
        self.methods_list.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.methods_list.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.methods_list.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.methods_list.setWindowTitle('Method Order')

        self.methods_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.methods_list)
        for method in self.methods:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(method)
            item.setData(method)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setDragEnabled(True)
            item.setDropEnabled(False)
            item.setCheckState(True)

            self.methods_model.appendRow(item)

        self.methods_model.itemChanged.connect(self.method_item_changed)
        self.methods_list.setModel(self.methods_model)
        self.methods_list.setMinimumHeight(
            self.methods_list.sizeHintForRow(0)
            * (self.methods_model.rowCount() + 2))

    def method_item_changed(self):
        print(self.methods_model.rowCount())
        i = 0
        new_methods = []
        while self.methods_model.item(i):
            if self.methods_model.item(i).checkState():
                new_methods.append(self.methods_model.item(i).data())
            i += 1
        self.methods = new_methods
        print(self.methods)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be in your slot for the `itemChanged` signal. You can always overload the `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent` to then determine the index changed, call the original method with `super()`, and then move that index when the drop happens.

Comment: If you need help with an example using `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent`, which may be the better way to do this, I can propose this as an answer with sample code.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thankyou @AlexanderHuszagh an example would be wonderful

Comment: Thanks for the link @eyllanesc, I've edited my question.

Comment: @JamesDowns in my answer I pointed out the reason for this behavior, besides I do not see the need to keep track of the checked items continuously, it is normal to do that logic when necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an item moves from position `i` to position `j`, what is done is:

- Insert an item in position `j`
- Copy the data to the new item, at this moment the `itemChanged` signal is emitted and therefore you see that there are elements of more
- Delete the item that was in the position `i`.

That is the reason for that behavior. But I do not understand the need to have that list updated. the normal thing is to obtain the checked items in demand that is to say have a function that is called and calculate it when necessary.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.methods = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.create_methods_list()
        layout.addWidget(self.methods_list)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def create_methods_list(self):
        self.methods_list = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.methods_list.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QListView.InternalMove)
        self.methods_list.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.methods_list.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.methods_list.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.methods_list.setDragEnabled(True)

        self.methods_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.methods_list)
        for method in self.methods:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(method)
            item.setData(method)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setDragEnabled(True)
            item.setDropEnabled(False)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            self.methods_model.appendRow(item)

        self.methods_list.setModel(self.methods_model)
        self.methods_list.setMinimumHeight(
            self.methods_list.sizeHintForRow(0)
            * (self.methods_model.rowCount() + 2))

    def get_items_Checked(self):
        checkeds = []
        for i in range(self.methods_model.rowCount()):
            it = self.methods_model.item(i)
            if it is not None and it.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                checkeds.append(it.text())
        return checkeds


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thankyou, you were right I had no reason for updating the list with every change. Once I moved your get_items_checked method to a push button rather than the listview callback I got the results I wanted.